# java code why println 10?

Tags: java, integer

```
public class Exa {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer b = new Integer(10);
        add(b);
        System.out.println(b.intValue());
   }

    public static void add(Integer b){
        int i = b.intValue();
        i += 3;
        b = new Integer(i);
        System.out.println("b="+b+",i="+i);
    }
}
```

I wrote the above code, and run output 10. Why did it not change?

Why output 10, please give detailed instructions，thanks！

Comment: You made a new `Integer`.  Did you really expect the old one to change when you did that?

Comment: Are you sure the output is not b=13,i=13 and then 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method local variable b in your main method is different from the method local variable in your `add()` method. Changing one won't affect the other.

```
b = new Integer(i);
```

Here you are referring to the variable in the `add(Integer b)` method not the variable in the main method.

> *Java is always pass-by-value. Unfortunately, they decided to call the location of an object a "reference". When we pass the value of an object, we are passing the reference to it. This is confusing to beginners.*
>
> (Extracted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40523/2408342) by [erlando](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4192/erlando))

Answer (score 0):

The value does not change because you only assign `b` locally inside the `add` method. In Java, you can not change the value of an Integer, you only change the reference. To have the intended side effect, you could wrap `b` in an object.